# Can't display data from one to one relationship, just render from one model

Tags: python, django

Using the django auth user model
And my PROFILE model like this:

```
// models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PROFILE(models.Model):
    userID = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True
    )
    idCity_FK = models.ForeignKey(CITY)
```

And my view to display the information about the current user:

```
//views.py
class ViewProfile_vw(DetailView):
    template_name = 'profile.html'

    def get_object(self):
        currentUser = self.request.user
        return get_object_or_404(PROFILE, userID=currentUser.id)
```

And my html file to render fields from both models:

```
//profile.html
<h1>Hello {{ object.email }}</h1>
<p>City:{{ object.idCity_FK }}</p>
```

My browser only display the name of the city, but doesn't show the email. The user have an email and the id is the same at the "one to one" fields.

How could I display the data from the user model?

Comment: Did you tried `{{ object.userID.email }}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you don't have an email field. If you're using Django's auth, then the Django `User` class *does* have an email, so you can access it via `object.userID.email`.

Note, including ID in your field names isn't a very good idea since it isn't an id, its an object relation.

Comment: It works perfectly!
Actually I did not include the "id" in the name, it is just an example of my code, and I was trying to explain my self in the best way. But your comment about its an object relation make me understand it better.